# "Action" column in a DataReader

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have an "action" column in my repeater which shows actions a user can select for an item.  The column contains ASP.NET HyperLink or LinkButton controls.  Some actions are based on whether a user is in a role, which I determine programatically.  I'm struggling with the best way to dynamically generate this column when I populate the repeater.  Now I am assigning in-line code to the Visible property of each control, but I feel that is sloppy and not very straight forward.  Would I be better served using a PlaceHolder control and populating that at runtime?  What kind of methods do other people use for situations such as this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "normal" way to apply any sort of dynamic rendering to a Template based control such as the `Repeater` is to handle the `ItemCreated` or `ItemDataBound` events.

In your particular case, you could check appropriate conditions within that event handler and toggle the visibility of the relevant "Action" column.

Also, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681057/retrieve-the-value-of-td-in-repeater) where Ian Quigley posted a code snippet that should serve as a good example for you. It may also help to read my own answer which shows how to use visibility toggling in inline code.